# Getting a non Spring Boot program such as ActiveMQ to work with Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have modified my original question slightly to better reflect my question.  I have a non-Spring Boot application that I would like to have working with the Spring Cloud Config Server.  I have searched around online and tried many things but it seems like the crux of my issue is that the server only works within a Spring Boot context.  Although ActiveMQ is a Spring application already, it seems non-trivial to convert it to be a Spring Boot one.

I would like to have an `ActiveMQ Broker` that is configured from the Spring Cloud Config.  My local settings within the application.properties should be replaced by those that come from the server.  This works in other servers I work on, now I need it to work for my Broker Filter plugins.

I added the following to activemq.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </list>
   </property>
</bean>

NOTE: Several base packages omitted here but are similar to:
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap"/>

<!-- enables annotation based configuration -->
<context:annotation-config />
```

After doing so I was able to get various `@Value` annotations to work with settings coming from my application.properties but the whole `Spring Cloud Config Server` thing seems to not replace my local application.properties file settings.  Other Spring Boot application I work on do so I know the server is fine.

I have added the following jars to the apache-activemq-5.12.0\lib\extra directory:

```
spring-aop-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-actuator-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-commons-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-config-client-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-context-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-starter-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-starter-config-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-crypto-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Why do you have `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` ? And why do you have `application.properties` in both?

Comment: Desperately trying to get this to work and am overlapping in ideas.  I probably only need one and will likely remove one during clean up.  Pertaining to getting a non-Spring Boot program, as ActiveMQ is in my case, to work with the config server, do you have any input?

Comment: Have you tried with PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer only? This is the one which reads from external properties file

Comment: @jny - yes.  I am now trying with org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: Is there any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

`refreshendpoint` is not necessarily initialized when the constructor is called. You need to add a method annotation with `@PostConstruct` (or implement `InitializingBean` and implement `afterPropertiesSet` method) in which you'll perform `refreshendpoint.refresh();` , e.g:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    refreshendpoint.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Correct.  I now realize the folly of that test which was just to see if it was being loaded.  The replacement of the application.properties is my chief concern.  I will edit my original post to omit this part of the question.  My main question is still unanswered though.